# Se puede guardar un parámetro de URL en caché?

Tags: php, url, cache

Pido por favor su ayuda para saber si es posible almacenar un parámetro, recibido por URL, en el caché del navegador. Por ejemplo:

Tengo la siguiente URL con el parámetro:

misitio.com/login.php?id=8

Quisiera que ese 'id=8' se guarde en el caché del navegador, de modo que cada vez que ingrese a 'misitio.com/login.php' lo redirija a 'misitio.com/login.php?id=8'

Otro ejemplo es, si yo ahora ingreso a misitio.com/login.php?id=9, se me actualiza dicho parametro en el caché del navegador, en ese caso me debe redigir siempre a  'misitio.com/login.php?id=9'

Espero haberme hecho entender, muchas gracias

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. Generalmente las redirecciones se hacen desde el [archivo `.htaccess`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/es/howto/htaccess.html) no desde el *caché del navegador*. Considera que cuando se ingresa a una web habrá tantos navegadores como usuarios, por lo que gestionar redirecciones desde el navegador sería totalmente absurdo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscas se puede solucionar de dos maneras  Una `Cookie`  o una variable de `sesion`

Para crear una cookie puedes:

```html
/*primer parametro nombre de la cookie, 
Segundo el valor y por ultimo el tiempo expira en 1 hora */

setcookie("usuario", $id, time()+3600);

//para acceder a su valor es de la siguiente manera
$valor = $_COOKIE['usuario'];
echo $valor;
```

Para crear una variable de sesión

```html
session_start()  // esto inicializar la sesion

$_SESSION["usuario"] = $id;


//para obtener el valor de la sesion 
$valor = $_SESSION["usuario"];
echo $valor;
```

Diferencias entre los dos metodos :

**Cookie :**

- Se almacena en el navegador (lado del cliente).
- Cualquiera puede ver su valor
- Tu eliges el tiempo de caducidad.
- Si el usuario cierra el navegador  y vuelve a abrirlo la cookie sigue
  ahi.

**Session :**

- Se almacena en el servidor
- Solo la sesion actual del navegador tiene acceso a su valor
- Si el navegador se cierra su valor se borra.

Aun faltan mas Diferencias. pero esas son las basicas

Comment: Muchas gracias, es la respuesta que estaba esperando :)

Comment: nada. no olvides puntuar :)